# In bash, how can I echo the variable value, not the variable name?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want echo a variable's value in a bash script using a for loop.

Example:

```
var1=test1;
var2=test2; 
for i in seq 1 2
do 
    echo "$var$i";
done
```

My output:

```
1
2
```

But I want to echo this:

```
test1
test2
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how identifiers work. If you want to loop through a set of variables like that, use array instead. 
Here's what is happening: Only $i is printed as 1 and 2, $var has no value so it is not printed.

In "$var$i" , $var and $i are treated as separate variables.